# what's the difference between direct function call and call() apply() in closure

Tags: javascript, function

I read this snippet in the definitive guide:

```
function not(f)
{
  return function()
  {
    var result=f.apply(this,arguments);
    return !result;
  }
}
```

What I can't understand is, since this function `f` is in the closure, it's `this` is already `this`, why wouldn't this snippet just directly use `var result=f(arguments);`?

I even read some `call`s with undefined/null as the first parameter which I think can completely be replaced with direct call:

```
...
while(i>len)
{
  if(i in a)
     accumulator=f.call(undefined,accumulator,a[i],i,a);
  i++;
}
...
```

Why did the author use call() but not direct call? are there any difference between direct function call and `call()` with undefined as it's first parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var result=f(arguments);
```

...Will call `f()` passing a single argument, the `arguments` object.

```
var result=f.apply(this,arguments);
```

...Will call `f()` passing the arguments in the `arguments` object individually (so to speak).

So let's say `f()` was defined as:

```
function f(a,b,c) {
    // do something with a, b, c
    return c;
}
```

Then given three arguments `1,2,3` the direct call with `arguments` is like this:

```
f([1,2,3]);
```

(Note that `arguments` is *array-like;* it isn't an actual array.)

Whereas the `.apply()` version is like this:

```
f(1,2,3);
```

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks! Very clearly explained! But what about the `call()` with undefined as first argument in the second snippet?

Comment: In that case, if the code is not in strict mode, `undefined` is replaced by the global object (but only where a native function object is being called, it may not work like that for built–in methods or host methods). See ECMA [§15.3.4.4](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4) and [§13.2.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.1)

Comment: Yes, what RobG said. Out of context I couldn't say what benefit that might have for the code snippet you show for `.call()`. (Seems to be completely unrelated to the reason for using `.apply()` in the other code snippet.)

Comment: Can anyone give speed comparison and the use case when to use what.?